# separate nested parentheses in c#

Tags: c#, regex, split, nested, parentheses

I want to take values from inside to out parentheses in given string. So, if there is parenthese(s) in my string, firstly i must to reach deepest parentheses. After, i must take later parentheses how is combined previous string. And i must make these process along the string.

**Example Input:**

```
C1 AND [C2 OR C3 OR [C4 OR [C5 AND C6] AND C7]] OR C8
```

**Output:**

```
C5 AND C6
C4 OR [C5 AND C6] AND C7
C2 OR C3 OR [C4 OR [C5 AND C6] AND C7]
C1 AND [C2 OR C3 OR [C4 OR [C5 AND C6] AND C7]] OR C8
```

Comment: This is not meant to be done with regex, it needs some algorithms and maybe one or more stacks :)

Comment: I thought it can made with regex easily for i do not master in regex. Do i solve this problem with split methods ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a simple *stack* implementation; *regular expressions* are not good for such *parsing* problems:

```
private static IEnumerable<String> Nested(string value) {
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    yield break; // or throw exception

  Stack<int> brackets = new Stack<int>();

  for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; ++i) {
    char ch = value[i];

    if (ch == '[')
      brackets.Push(i);
    else if (ch == ']') {
      //TODO: you may want to check if close ']' has corresponding open '['
      // i.e. stack has values: if (!brackets.Any()) throw ...
      int openBracket = brackets.Pop();

      yield return value.Substring(openBracket + 1, i - openBracket - 1);
    }
  }

  //TODO: you may want to check here if there're too many '['
  // i.e. stack still has values: if (brackets.Any()) throw ... 

  yield return value;
}
```

...

```
string source = "C1 AND [C2 OR C3 OR [C4 OR [C5 AND C6] AND C7]] OR C8";

var result = Nested(source);
```

Print out:

```
// C5 AND C6
// C4 OR [C5 AND C6] AND C7
// C2 OR C3 OR [C4 OR [C5 AND C6] AND C7]
// C1 AND [C2 OR C3 OR [C4 OR [C5 AND C6] AND C7]] OR C8
Console.Write(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

Comment: That code solved my problem.Thanks very much for your help.